# How to restore php defaults in cpanel

Tags: php, cpanel

This is really embarrassing. I accidentally removed all my files in the server through a code. I manage to restore my website files but now Its not functioning properly due to php files being deleted (i think), many of the function is not working i.e. getimgsize() header() etc... And now I'm really at loss and been trying to fix it for like 2 days.

When I try to set the default in cpanel this error shows up
[image]
Any help would be appreciated thank you.

Comment: Contact your hosting provider, they will do it for you. Note backup your websites.

Comment: yeah already tried that but if thats the only way I think ill give up for now. since I've been trying to contact them since the problem occur and still no response

Comment: Just create a ticket and enjoy your day.

Comment: @Rafee Haha funny cause my hosting provider does not support ticketing, they removed it since 2014 and the only way to contact them is through phone. Is it time to change hosting provider? lel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

contact cpanel support at cpanel.net , they will be able to fix the things